# Python 3 Pandas Pivot Table to mimic Excel output

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following CSV data:

[image: csv data]

In a few clicks in Excel (2019), I can create the following pivot table:

[image: Excel Pivot Table]

I've been beating my brains out trying to get Pandas to mimic this pivot table. Column D is a copy of Column C and all I have to do is right click on on any cell in column D and select **Show Values As -> % of Parent Total** and the magic happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think this function is what you’re looking for:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table
Notice that this function differs fro the other Pivot method supported by a pandas dataframe as this function supports aggregation functions which you look like you need